# What does the error "Bad gateway" mean on Kibana Dashboard?

Tags: elasticsearch, haproxy, kibana-4

I have a "Elastic-search + Kibana" instance which has a lot of data. I have another HAProxy instance which redirects connection to Kibana dashboard. 
I am having a issue where the Kibana Dashboard isn't able to search (*) , it takes too much time & eventually throws this -:

[image]

I want to know why is this happening or what exactly "Bad Gateway" mean. Moreover what to can be done to solve this.

Comment: That typically means that an intermediate proxy wasn't able to satisfy a request with a backend. This probably means that HAProxy is either unable to route requests to Elasticsearch, or requests are timing out. Check your HAProxy logs.

Comment: Even if i directly access the kibana dashboard , it says 
`Error, Visualize: Gateway Timeout`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution , it was the issue of Elastic_search tuning. I had to allocate half of the memory to ES_HEAP_SIZE & did some tweaks on elasticsearch.yml which doesn't allow JVM to swap memory.

Answer (score -3):

I got the same problem, I restarted my browser, then it back to normal again.